# Extracting certain strings to concatenate by ID in R

Tags: r

I am trying to extract certain treatment methods and then concatenate them by ID in R using tidyverse functions. Could someone please help out with the code please? I have been trying stringr but have not been successful. I have this picture of what I have and what I need to get to. The data on the left is an example of what I have and the data on the right is what I need it to look like. The list of strings I am pulling out here is A, B, and D. [image: The data on the left is an example of what I have and the data on the right is what I need it to look like. The list of strings I am pulling out here is A, B, and D.]

Comment: which one is right and which one is left? When you say left is it the small table or the long table?

Comment: left is the long table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An option is to `filter` the 'Treatment' to subset the rows, then do a group by 'ID' and `paste` the `sort`ed `unique` values of 'Treatment'

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
  filter(Treatment %in% c("A", "B", "D")) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarise(Treatment = toString(sort(unique(Treatment))))
```

---

Or with `base R`

```
aggregate(Treatment ~ ID, unique(subset(df1, Treatment %in% c('A', 'B', 'D')), toString)
```